# jQuery Validation on a static form

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am using ajax and JSON to retrieve information into a form. However the user is able to edit the fields but the new data won't go anywhere. I need validation on the fields but don't know how to make it work without adding an external file in the "action" part in HTML form. Thanks for any help.

My HTML

```
<form id="summary" method="get" action="">
<h2>Summary Form</h2>


<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name"/>

<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>

<label for="roomtype">Room Type</label>
<input type="text" name="roomtype" id="roomtype" placeholder="Room Type"/>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
<label for="checkin">Checkin</label>
<input type="text" name="checkin" id="checkin" placeholder=" Check in"/>

<label for="checkout">Checkout</label>
<input type="text" name="checkout" id="checkout" placeholder=" Check out"/>

<label for="noofnights">Number of nights</label>
<input type="number" name="noofnights" id="noofnights" placeholder="Number of nights"/>

<label for="totalstay">Total Stay </label>
<input type="number" name="totalstay" id="totalstay" placeholder="Total stay"/>

<button type="button">Update</button>
<button type="button" id="button1">Book</button>
```

MY jQuery Validation

```
$(function() {


$("form[id='summary']").validate({

rules: {

  firstname: "required",
  lastname: "required",
  email: {
    required: true,

    email: true
  },
},
// validation error messages
messages: {
  firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
  lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
  email: "Please enter a valid email address"
},


submitHandler: function(form) {
  form.submit();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the button type to submit it will work perfectly. Hope this helps :). Please refer following code spinets

```
<form id="summary" method="get" action="">
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
<label for="roomtype">Room Type</label>
<input type="text" name="roomtype" id="roomtype" placeholder="Room Type" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<label for="checkin">Checkin</label>
<input type="text" name="checkin" id="checkin" placeholder=" Check in" />
<label for="checkout">Checkout</label>
<input type="text" name="checkout" id="checkout" placeholder=" Check out" />
<label for="noofnights">Number of nights</label>
<input type="number" name="noofnights" id="noofnights" placeholder="Number of nights" />
<label for="totalstay">Total Stay </label>
<input type="number" name="totalstay" id="totalstay" placeholder="Total stay" />
<!-- <button type="button">Update</button> -->
<!-- this change makes it work -->
<button type="submit">Update</button>

<button type="button" id="button1">Book</button>
<form/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $("form[id='summary']").validate({

        rules: {

            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,

                email: true
            },
        },
        // validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },


        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I clicked the "update" button it just refreshed the page and didn't show any of the validation errors I have in place

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> is this plugin added to the source ?

Comment: That plugin is no longer available. I have <script src="vendor/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: This script works <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>